# Mongodb bson_ext InvalidDocument error

Tags: ruby, mongodb, bson, bson-ext

I want to use bson_ext with mongodb but I get a strange error.

I tried to run this ruby test code :

```
require 'mongo'
include Mongo
mongoClient = MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017)
```

and the error was :

> /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bson-1.9.2/lib/bson/bson_c.rb:20:in `serialize': BSON.serialize takes a Hash but got a Hash (BSON::InvalidDocument)
>       from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bson-1.9.2/lib/bson/bson_c.rb:20:in`serialize'
>       ...

I ran bundle install with the following Gemfile :

```
gem "bson"
gem "bson_ext"
gem "mongo"
```

(Installed versions are all `1.9.2` but ruby is 2.0.0)

I really don't know what to do. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce this but it worked for me with ruby 2.0.0p247

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

I installed the same versions of gems.

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bson (1.9.2, 1.3.1)
bson_ext (1.9.2, 1.3.1)
bundler (1.5.1)
CFPropertyList (2.2.0)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
mongo (1.9.2, 1.3.1)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
```

Trying to connect

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'mongo'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> include Mongo
=> Object
irb(main):003:0> mongoClient = MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017)
=> #<Mongo::MongoClient:0x007f971b96fd70 @host="localhost", @port=27017, @id_lock=#<Mutex:0x007f971b96fcd0>, @primary=["localhost", 27017], @primary_pool=#<Mongo::Pool:0x3fcb8dcb6e00 @host=localhost @port=27017 @ping_time= 0/1 sockets available up=true>, @mongos=false, @tag_sets=[], @acceptable_latency=15, @max_message_size=48000000, @max_bson_size=16777216, @slave_ok=nil, @ssl=nil, @unix=false, @socket_opts={}, @socket_class=Mongo::TCPSocket, @auths=[], @pool_size=1, @pool_timeout=5.0, @op_timeout=nil, @connect_timeout=30, @logger=nil, @read=:primary, @default_db="test", @write_concern={:w=>1, :j=>false, :fsync=>false, :wtimeout=>nil}, @read_primary=true>
```

Stopped the mongod to check its really connecting

```
irb(main):004:0> mongoClient = MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017)
Mongo::ConnectionFailure: Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:486:in `connect'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:693:in `setup'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:155:in `initialize'
from (irb):4:in `new'
from (irb):4
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I hope this helps.